# Window растянуть на весь рабочий стол

Tags: wpf

Как WPF Window растянуть на весь рабочий стол в не зависимости от количества мониторов и их расширений ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте свойство WindowState и перечисление WindowState.
Вот пример для вашей ситуации, когда нужно растянуть на весь рабочий стол окно:
Пример через Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

Пример через разметку самого окна:

```
<Window ...
    WindowState="Maximized">
...
</Window>
```

Comment: В этом случае оно занимает только основной монитор

Comment: Как быть если нужно расширить на все подключенные мониторы ?

Comment: Как бы другие мониторы на то и ДРУГИЕ мониторы, что они идут как ДРУГИЕ мониторы, считайте значит ширину всех мониторов и присваивайте ее своему окну